# C# XmlWriter - Add Elements in Element

Tags: c#, xmlreader, xmlwriter

currently I am working with the XmlWriter and wanted to ask how it is possible to write in an existing XML file, as an example:

a.xml

```
<info>
     <description>Test3</description>
     <loops>100</loops>
</info>
```

to add in `<Info>`, e.g.

```
<name>Test1</name>
```

position of `<name>` plays no role, but would be best if it is written before `</info>`, thus the last element.

```
<info>
     <description>Test3</description>
     <loops>100</loops>
     <name>Test1</name>
</info>
```

or:

```
<info>
     <name>Test1</name>
     <description>Test3</description>
     <loops>100</loops>
</info>
```

Comment: I made a lot of edits to your question. You should be aware that XML is case-sensitive, so your earlier elements with different capitalization between opening and closing tags would cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

`XmlWriter` class is fast but only writing in one direction, element by element. If you want to edit existing XML, the easiest way is to use LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // or XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath)
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("name", "Test1"));

doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `doc.Save(xmlFilePath);` because changes would be unsaved.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend you to use XmlReader and Writer, but if you are asking... I guess you just need to read your xml and then just rewrite it back, but with new node. For example

```
            XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
            d.Load("c:/a.xml");

            XmlNode root = d.FirstChild;
            if(root.HasChildNodes)
            {
                using(XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("c:/a.xml", Encoding.Default))
                {
                    writer.WriteStartDocument();
                    writer.WriteStartElement(root.Name);
                    foreach(XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement(node.Name);
                        writer.WriteValue(node.InnerText);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                        // writing new node after "loop" node
                        if (node.Name == "loop")
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement("name");
                            writer.WriteValue("test1");
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }

                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why do you not recommend XmlReader/Writer?